# A PHP function doesn't fetch the arguments

Tags: php, arguments

I'm still having problems with this code. I neet to set the argument to a function in order to convert it to a .mp3 file. Using this line : `$tts->setText($row['raspuns']);` doesn't happen anything but if i write `$tts->setText("Hello World!");` it works perfectly, which takes me to the conclusion that i have to find a correct code to make that tts get the text. Can anyone help me please?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Bot
        </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="bot.php "method="post">
            <lable>You:<input type="text" name="intrebare"></lable>
            <input type="submit" name="introdu" value="Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("robo") or die(mysql_error());

$intrebare=$_POST['intrebare'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM dialog where intrebare = '$intrebare'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = $result;
?>

<?php
require "tts.php";
$tts = new TextToSpeech();
$tts->setText($row['raspuns']);
//$tts->setText("Hello World!");
$tts->saveToFile("voice.mp3");
$file='voice.mp3';
?>

<div id="history">
<?php       

    while (true == ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
    echo "<b>The robot says: </b><br />";
    echo $row['raspuns'];
    echo "<embed src =\"$file\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>";
}
?>
</div>
```

Here's the tts.php file:

```
<?php
class TextToSpeech {
    public $mp3data;
    function __construct($text="") {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={$text}");
        }
    }

    function setText($text) {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={$text}");
            return  $this->mp3data;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function saveToFile($filename) {
        $filename = trim($filename);
        if(!empty($filename)) {
            return file_put_contents($filename,$this->mp3data);
        } else { return false; }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the content of your `$row`? are you sure you have valid text? And BTW, mysql_query is deprecated, use PDO or mysqli

Comment: $row is a row from database. I think it's valid because it works, it shows me what I need to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to doc of mysql_query,

> The returned result resource should be passed to mysql_fetch_array(),
>   and other functions for dealing with result tables, to access the
>   returned data.

so instead of

```
$row = $result;
```

You should have

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: I've already done that but nothing happens, no data is returned

Comment: You do it in your history section, but not at the top on the tts part.

Comment: ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for

Comment: ( ! ) Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\robo\tts.php on line 13

Comment: @DanielPatilea What is your DB schema for the dialog table? and can you make a print_r of the row?